# Derive formal or informal proofs using Modus Ponus and Deduction Theorem - Logic

Tags: propositional-calculus, axioms, formal-proofs

How do I show the following by producing formal or informal proofs?

1. ⊢ (¬A → ¬B) → (B → A )
2. ⊢ ¬B → (B → A)

I can use the Modus ponus (MP) rule, and deduction theorem (DT). And I have these 3 axioms:

1. α → (β → α) --- (A1)
2. (α → (β → γ)) → ((α → β) → (α → γ)) --- (A2)
3. (¬β → ¬α) → ((¬β → α) → β) --- (A3)

Thank you!

Comment: What have *you* tried, and where exactly did you get stuck? Show us your own effort!

Comment: "formal or informal proof" ???

Comment: Oh, thank you very much!! Im trying to work out how to solve this using the deduction theorem too

Comment: Why closed as a duplicate? It is not demanded here to leave the deduction theorem aside.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one:

$1\ \neg A \to \neg B \ Premise$

$2 \ B \ Premise$

$3 \ B \to (\neg A \to B) \ Axiom \ 1$

$4 \ \neg A \to B \ MP \ 2,3$

$5 \ (\neg A \to \neg B) \to ((\neg A \to B) \to A \ Axiom \ 3$

$6 \ (\neg A \to B) \to A \ MP \ 1,5$

$7 \ A \ MP \ 4,6$

This shows that $\{ \neg A \to \neg B, B \vdash A\}$

So, with two applications of DT, you're there.

Comment: thank you very much! Guess i need to practice more questions to get the hang of it

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted?... That fact on its own inspired me to read the answer. That reading on its own gave me a reason to upvote.

Answer (score -1):

Hint:

1) With DT we firstly conclude that it is enough to prove $\left\{ \neg A\to\neg B\right\} \vdash B\to A$
and based on that secondly that it is enough to prove $\left\{ \neg A\to\neg B,B\right\} \vdash A$.

2) With DT we firstly conclude that it is enough to prove $\left\{ \neg B\right\} \vdash B\to A$
and based on that secondly that it is enough to prove $\left\{ \neg B,B\right\} \vdash A$.

Now give that a try and tell us where you get stuck in the sequel.

Comment: Ah thats very helpful thank you! I managed to solve the second question, working on the first one now

Comment: Why is this anwer downvoted?